# How to display a animated gif in a screen saver plugin?

Tags: objective-c, macos, animated-gif, screensaver

Okay so I'm a new to objective-c. (irrelevant, but I'm looking forward to swift!:D) and I'm trying to create a screen saver plugin that will display an animated gif.

My first attempt was to create `NSBitmapImageRep` and to get the individual frames from the representations property `NSImageFrameCount` and `NSImageCurrentFrame` after getting a `NSData` (TIFFRepresentation compressed format) object from an `NSImage` object that was inited with contents from url.

It failed miserably.

Second attempt I made actually worked, but it didn't animate the gif. It only displayed the first frame. What I did was create an `NSImage` with url contents and then called the drawInRect within the ScreenSaverView drawRect method.

I tried one more time before coming to stack overflow for help. Here is my current code: [codebin](http://pastebin.com/kPDE9nPM)

For my most recent try, I thought maybe creating an `NSImageview` setting the image to the `NSImage` inited with contents from url again and drawing the view in the ScreenSaverView draw method. But it's pointless, because I'm creating a view in a view for no reason.

I'm stuck now and my question is:
How do you play an animated gif in a ScreenSaverView?

Comment: In a normal app context, you can just put an `NSImageView` in your view hierarchy, set its `image` to an `NSImage` loaded from an animating gif, and make sure the image view's `animates` property is `YES`. It might work to put such an image view in your `ScreenSaverView` and simply call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` in its `-animateOneFrame` method.

Comment: You would, of course, have to set the image view's frame correctly. To fill its superview, it should be set to its superview's **bounds**, not its frame. You would also want to set the autoresizing mask to make sure it tracks changes in the superview's size, and set the superview to autoresize its subviews, if it doesn't already. You would not override `-drawRect:` in your `ScreenSaverView` and definitely not invoke the image view's `-drawRect:` yourself. The image view will draw itself just as a consequence of being in the view hierarchy.

Comment: okay, thank you for the quick reply! I'm going to edit my code with your suggestions.

Comment: @KenThomases Would you want to post your comments as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal app context, you can just put an `NSImageView` in your view hierarchy, set its `image` to an `NSImage` loaded from an animating gif, and make sure the image view's `animates` property is `YES`. It might work to put such an image view in your `ScreenSaverView` and simply call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` in its `-animateOneFrame` method.

You would, of course, have to set the image view's frame correctly. To fill its superview, it should be set to its superview's bounds, not its frame. You would also want to set the autoresizing mask to make sure it tracks changes in the superview's size, and set the superview to autoresize its subviews, if it doesn't already. You would not override `-drawRect:` in your `ScreenSaverView` and definitely not invoke the image view's `-drawRect:` yourself. The image view will draw itself just as a consequence of being in the view hierarchy.